# SC-RNA seq percent.mito

Tags: scrnaseq

Is that possible that the percent.mito level is zero? I have done vlnplot and it shows that its percent.mito level is zero. Does that mean my  mitochondrial gene didn't detect?

[image]

It is violin plot. And the command is:
[image]

Comment: Sorry hua, but I find it difficult to understand. Could you clarify what is "percen.mito" ? It seems like it should be a function or a property of your data but I'm not sure. Also, could you explain what is "VlnPlot" ? It seems like a violin plot, but I'm not sure, perhaps the image didn't get attached (upload just a link and we will add it).

Comment: Your genome likely doesn't title mitochondrial genes `MT-something`, so you'll need to change how `mito.genes` is created.

Comment: Is "percent.mito level" the percent of reads mapping to genes annotated as mitochondrial? Are the mitochondrial genes annotated? Note you have [edit] button you can use to improve your question.

Comment: You should put "Seurat" in your question, and add a Seurat tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just come across a similar issue. It seems the mouse and human mitochondrial genes use mixed capitalizations. See the following PR for details:

https://github.com/Hoohm/dropSeqPipe/pull/43

Bottom line is, if you ignore the case in the grep pattern it might work (assuming you use human/mouse):

```
mito.genes <- grep("^mt-", rownames(shox2crepos_mtmg@data), value=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have solve this problem after your instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that the bit of code you copied from the Seurat vignette is not working on the gene names you have.  Look at the code.  If none of your gene names begin with "MT-", none will be identified as mitochondrial.